# Close other tabs if one is open (react-native-collapsible)

Tags: react-native, accordion

Hi guys I just wanted to ask if it is possible to close other tabs if one is open. here's my code

```
    const [bookingList, setBookingList] = useState(true);
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(true);
    const [ongoing, setOnGoing] = useState(true);

 const ToggleBookingList = () => {
        setBookingList(!bookingList);
    };

    const ToggleCompletedList = () => {
        setCompleted(!completed);
    };

    const ToggleOngoingList = () => {
        setOnGoing(!ongoing);
    };

 return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
            <Image 
                source={require('../../Assets/Icons/overlay-01.png')}
                style={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}
            />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 25, marginTop: 15}}>Trip List, Monday 4:20 PM</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleBookingList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Upcoming</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleCompletedList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Completed</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleOngoingList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Ongoing</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:4, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Collapsible collapsed={bookingList} align="center">
                    <FlatList
                        contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingBottom: 20}}
                        data={userBookingData}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
                        renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp navigation={navigation} driversLocation={route.params} {...item}/>}
                    /> 
                </Collapsible>
                <Collapsible collapsed={completed} align="center">
                    <Text>Completed Lists</Text>
                </Collapsible>
                <Collapsible collapsed={ongoing} align="center">
                    <Text>OnGoing Lists</Text>
                </Collapsible>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

The only problem with this code is that if I open the Upcoming button and open also the completed button both are going to pop up and I want to prevent that from happening . Is it possible without accordion ?

I am using `react-native-collapsible`

PS : I don't want to use the Accordion ,  is enough for me

Comment: `Collapsible` components are the ones that are possible to open and close right ? So you've 3 such components inside your module. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you've all the states relevant to `collapsible` component inside the same object. As a result, you can set all the three of them at once, only having a single item expanded and other 2 in collapsed mode.

```
const [isCollapsedArray, setIsCollapsedArray] = useState({
    bookingList:true,
    completed:true,
    ongoing:true
});

const ToggleBookingList = () => {
    setIsCollapsedArray(collapsed => ({
        bookingList:!collapsed.bookingList,
        completed:true,
        ongoing:true
    }));
};

const ToggleCompletedList = () => {
    setIsCollapsedArray(collapsed => ({
        bookingList:true,
        completed:!collapsed.completed,
        ongoing:true
    }));
};

const ToggleOngoingList = () => {
    setIsCollapsedArray(collapsed => ({
        bookingList:true,
        completed:true,
        ongoing:!collapsed.ongoing
    }));
};

return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
        <Image 
            source={require('../../Assets/Icons/overlay-01.png')}
            style={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 25, marginTop: 15}}>Trip List, Monday 4:20 PM</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleBookingList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Upcoming</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleCompletedList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Completed</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToggleOngoingList} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Ongoing</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:4, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsedArray.bookingList} align="center">
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingBottom: 20}}
                    data={userBookingData}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
                    renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp navigation={navigation} driversLocation={route.params} {...item}/>}
                /> 
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsedArray.completed} align="center">
                <Text>Completed Lists</Text>
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsedArray.ongoing} align="center">
                <Text>OnGoing Lists</Text>
            </Collapsible>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: This will give me an error : `collapsesd.bookingList is undefined not an ojbect`

Comment: Can you tell me which code line gives the error ?

Comment: if i press the `ToggleOngoingList = () => { }` it's not reading this `!collapsed.bookingList,` . this part here is the error sir

Comment: same for the `ToggleCompletedList = () => {}` and `ToggleOngoingList = () => {}`

Comment: fixied it :) it should be `setIsCollapsedArray` on every toggle

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer. Can you please check it and tell me whether it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code

```
const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState("");

const ToggleItem = (item) => {
    setExpandedItem(currentItem=>(currentItem==item?'':item))
};

return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
        <Image 
            source={require('../../Assets/Icons/overlay-01.png')}
            style={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 25, marginTop: 15}}>Trip List, Monday 4:20 PM</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>toggleItem("upcoming")} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Upcoming</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>toggleItem("completed")} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Completed</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>toggleItem("ongoing")} style={{paddingTop:15, paddingBottom:15, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, borderRadius:25,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Ongoing</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:4, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <Collapsible collapsed={expandedItem==="upcoming"} align="center">
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingBottom: 20}}
                    data={userBookingData}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
                    renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp navigation={navigation} driversLocation={route.params} {...item}/>}
                /> 
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible collapsed={expandedItem==="completed"} align="center">
                <Text>Completed Lists</Text>
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible collapsed={expandedItem==="ongoing"} align="center">
                <Text>OnGoing Lists</Text>
            </Collapsible>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

also can move names to consts

```
const collapsables = {
    UPCOMING:"upcoming",
    COMPLETED:"completed",
    ONGOING:"ongoing",
}
```

Comment: Means you always want 1 item to be open??